# How to use ExtJS7 without Sencha Cmd?

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I am trying to migrate ExtJS6 project that doesn't use Sencha Cmd to ExtJS7 and keep it that way. Before it was enough to include the following static files to get it working:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext/classic/theme-triton/resources/theme-triton-all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext/packages/charts/classic/triton/resources/charts-all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext/packages/ux/classic/triton/resources/ux-all.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/ext/ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ext/classic/theme-triton/theme-triton.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ext/packages/charts/classic/charts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ext/packages/ux/classic/ux.js"></script>
```

I downloaded the whole ExtJS7 npm tree but I can't find these files. All I was able to find was `ext-all.js`, but that doesn't include charts or Triton theme or UX, only the core.

Do these files still exist somewhere in the new npm repository? If not, has anyone figured a way to build these static files from the sources (or achieve a similar functionality)?

(I understand that they really want you to use sencha-cmd, but I really want to use static files if that's still possible.)

Comment: I have the same problem. I've found that the theme source can be built by generating a new Application using Cmd, then `build` the application and you have the sources. The default theme is "theme-triton", but you can change it in the file "app.json". For the Charts package, the components files are given in the SDK (ext/packages/charts/src), but I am not able to build the final package, that is "charts.js" or "charts-debug.js".

Comment: I found it for the Charts package: using Sencha Cmd, got to the SDK folder, then in the sub folder `ext\packages\charts`. Then call the sencha command `sencha package build`. This will build the expected files in `ext/build/packages/charts`.

Comment: You can do the same for Themes since themes are packages. But you have to use the option `sencha package build --destination=my_folder` otherwise a bug makes the build into the current directory with a weird name.

Comment: Was able to find all the files in this repo under "build" subfolder https://github.com/tremez/extjs-gpl